# safe input from user. is this function ok?

Tags: php, string

hi i just reinstalled all my server for a virus.
in my php o ckeck string from users with this function:

```
function make_safe($variable)
{
    $variable=nl2br($variable);
    $variable=mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($variable, '<span><p><b><strong><i><u><br><hr><a><img>')));
    return $variable;
}
```

is this function safe enuoght?
should i have to change something... any problems with images that i link form external websites?

Comment: Never use `mysql*` functions in new code.

Comment: Id say its kinda safe. But you should think about using mysqli instead of mysql. because mysql is too old.

Comment: safe in what context actually? If you use that in combination with mysql functions, you should consider switching to prepared statements (PDO/MySqli)

Comment: Also, you ought to read the warning regarding strip_tags: "This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you allow using allowable_tags, including the style and onmouseover attributes that a mischievous user may abuse when posting text that will be shown to other users." http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how an image you don't download on your serveur could possibly damage it.
It seems safe to me.

If you still need to check for a faulty code, that's probably somewhere else ;)